# How to get backface state for faces in view?

Tags: python, 3d-view

Is this value somewhere? I can only calculate faces that are not aligned to a view. But this method is not accurate.

Here is my simple method to select faces that not aligned to view

```
import bpy, bmesh

def view_matrix():
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            r3d = area.spaces.active.region_3d
    return r3d.view_matrix

view_matrix = view_matrix()
# Better to use view_matrix instead of perspective_matrix
view_direction = -view_matrix.inverted().to_3x3().col[2]
#view_direction = rv3d.perspective_matrix.inverted().to_3x3().col[2]
angle_threshold = 1.4 # in radians

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
    
    for f in bm.faces:
        angle = f.normal.angle(view_direction)
        if angle < angle_threshold:
            f.select = True
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Scene for test [image]

In the scene
[image]

after running the script, we have some not selected backfaces
[image]

if we increase angle from 1.4 to 1.5, it selects some aligned faces
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code that works with what you have? Perhaps we can adapt it to work with the current view angle.

Comment: FYI information the file you shared is not downloadable: that requires a popup blocked by the navigators for security reasons. Please use https://blend-exchange.com/ instead.

Comment: The rules here for defining that a face is aligned are not so clear to me. Do you mean faces that are front facing?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience.  Uploaded on proper site. Rule is simple: select all backfaces

Comment: Have you tried?         f.select = f.normal.dot(view_direction) > 0

Comment: f.select = f.normal.dot(view_direction) > 0 did not help. It selects like on third screen

Comment: When you say "select all backfaces" do you mean faces with **normals** that face away from the view? Or do you mean faces that are on the objects side that is not facing the view? If you mean the faces normals then it looks like your script is working, being that your 2 cubes have their normals inverted

Comment: Yes, faces with normals that are not look at the view, so they transparent if Backface Culling is on. I need somehow add to selection faces that on screen 2 and avoid the faces on screen 3 being selected.